# Ошибка: System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат

Tags: c#

Делаю шифр Цезаря и появилась ошибка

Ошибка: System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат."

В строке: int step = Convert.ToInt32(sd);

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lab_1._1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static string al = "абвгдеєжзыиёъэйклмнопрстуфхцшщьюя 0123456789";
        private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)``
        {
            textBox2.Text = ori(textBox1.Text);
        }
        public string ori(string inp)
        {
            StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
            string s = textBox1.Text;
            string sd = textBox3.Text;
            int step = Convert.ToInt32(sd);
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < al.Length; j++)
                    if(s[i] == al[j]) code.Append(al[(j+step)% al.Length]);
            return code.ToString();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = org(textBox1.Text);
        }
        public string org(string inp)
        {
            StringBuilder code = new StringBuilder();
            string s = textBox1.Text;
            string sd = textBox3.Text;
            int step = Convert.ToInt32(sd);
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < al.Length; j++)
                    if (s[i] == al[j]) code.Append(al[(j - step + al.Length) % al.Length]);
            return code.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Windows form программа]

Comment: значит в sd не строка. Или строка, содержащая не только цифры, которую нельзя конвертировать в целое число.

Comment: Там есть и числа и буквы

Comment: ну вот вам и ответ. Какой число по-вашему должно получиться из букв?

Comment: Ну нужно сделать шифр Цезаря

Comment: ну делайте, никто не возражает

Comment: Шифр Цезаря, заключается в том, что нужно допустим слово МИР перенести по алфавиту на указанное количество букв, т.е.  НЙУ (перенос на 1 букву)

Comment: это всем известно. Ваша проблема-то в чем заключается?

Comment: Убедитесь в том, что в переменной sd были точно цифры. Лучше для таких случае использовать ```int.TryParse(out step)```. Этот метод вернет true, если успешно распарсили строку, иначе - false